# Wrong index being used when selecting top rows

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, plsql, indexing

I have a simple query, which selects top 200 rows ordered by one of the columns filtered by other indexed column. The confusion is why is that the query plan in PL/SQL Developer shows that this index is used **only** when I'm selecting all rows, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT *
 FROM cr_proposalsearch ps
 WHERE UPPER(ps.customerpostcode) like 'MK3%'
 ORDER BY ps.ProposalNumber DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 200
```

Plan shows that it uses index CR_PROPOSALSEARCH_I1, which is an index on two columns: PROPOSALNUMBER & UPPER(CUSTOMERNAME), this takes **0.985s** to execute:
[image: query with ROWNUM]

If I get rid of ROWNUM condition, the plan is what I expect and it executes in **0.343s**:
[image: query without ROWNUM]

Where `index XIF25CR_PROPOSALSEARCH is on CR_PROPOSALSEARCH (UPPER(CUSTOMERPOSTCODE));`

How come?

**EDIT**: I have gathered statistics on `cr_proposalsearch` table and both query plans now show that they use `XIF25CR_PROPOSALSEARCH` index.

Comment: Two different queries, two different result sets, why shouldn't there be two different explain plans?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Including the ROWNUM changes the optimizer's calculations about which is the more efficient path.

When you do a top-n query like this, it doesn't necessarily mean that Oracle will get all the rows, fully sort them, then return the top ones.  The `COUNT STOPKEY` operation in the execution plan indicates that Oracle will only perform the underlying operations until it has found the number of rows you asked for.

The optimizer has calculated that the full query will acquire and sort 77K rows.  If it used this plan for the top-n query, it would have to do a large sort of those rows to find the top 200 (it wouldn't necessarily have to fully sort them, as it wouldn't care about the exact order of rows past the top; but it would have to look over all of those rows).

The plan for the top-n query uses the other index to avoid having to sort at all.  It considers each row in order, checks whether it matches the predicate, and if so returns it.  When it's returned 200 rows, it's done.  Its calculations have indicated that this will be more efficient for getting a small number of rows.  (It may not be right, of course; you haven't said what the relative performance of these queries is.)

If the optimizer were to choose this plan when you ask for all rows, it would have to read through the entire index in descending order, getting each row from the table by ROWID as it goes to check against the predicate.  This would result in a lot of extra I/O and inspecting many rows that would not be returned.  So in this case, it decides that using the index on `customerpostcode` is more efficient.

If you gradually increase the number of rows to be returned from the top-n query, you will probably find a tipping point where the plan switches from the first to the second.  Just from the costs of the two plans, I'd guess this might be around 1,200 rows.

Comment: genius, the treshold is 1166, how did you know this? I've added timings and details of other index. If you tell the query to use index as per @Kevin Burton's answer, the time is always around 0.3s

Comment: pls note, maximum rownum count for me will always be 200. This means XIF25CR_PROPOSALSEARCH will never be used? Is there another optimization option I could use here?

Comment: I guessed that that cost of the first plan would scale up linearly. 6 x 951 = 5,706, pretty close to the second plan's cost of 5,512.  So I estimated that the tipping point would be close to 6 x 200 = 1200.

Answer (score 4):

If you are sure your stats are up to date and that the index is selective enough, you could tell oracle to use the index

```
SELECT  *
FROM   (SELECT /*+ index(ps XIF25CR_PROPOSALSEARCH) */  *
        FROM     cr_proposalsearch ps
        WHERE    UPPER (ps.customerpostcode) LIKE 'MK3%'
        ORDER BY ps.proposalnumber DESC)
WHERE  ROWNUM <= 200
```

(I would only recommend this approach as a last resort)

If I were doing this I would first tkprof the query to see actually how much work it is doing,

e.g: the cost of index range scans could be way off

forgot to mention....
You should check the actual cardinality:

```
SELECT count(*)  FROM cr_proposalsearch ps  WHERE UPPER(ps.customerpostcode) like 'MK3%'
```

and then compare it to the cardinality in the query plan.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have a perfectly fitting index. The index CR_PROPOSALSEARCH_I1 can be used to retrieve the rows in descending order of the attribute PROPOSALNUMBER. It's probably chosen because Oracle can avoid to retrieve all matching rows, sort them according to the ORDER BY clause and then discard all rows except the first ones.

Without the ROWNUM condition, Oracle uses the XIF25CR_PROPOSALSEARCH index (you didn't give any details about it) because it's probably rather selective regarding the WHERE clause. But it will require to sort the result afterwards. This is probably the more efficent plan based on the assumption that you'll retrieve all rows.

Since either index is a trade-off (one is better for sorting, the other one better for applying the WHERE clause), details such as ROWNUM determine which execution plan Oracle chooses.

Answer (score 1):

This condition:

```
WHERE UPPER(ps.customerpostcode) like 'MK3%'
```

is not continuous, that is you cannot preserve a single ordered range for it.

So there are two ways to execute this query:

1. Order by number then filter on code.
2. Filter on code then order by number.

Method `1` is able to user an index on number which gives you linear execution time (top `100` rows would be selected `2` times faster than top `200`, provided that number and code do not correlate).

Method `2` is able to use a range scan for coarse filtering on code (the range condition would be something like `code >= 'MK3' AND code < 'MK4'`), however, it requires a sort since the order of number cannot be preserved in a composite index.

The sort time depends on the number of top rows you are selecting too, but this dependency, unlike that for method `1`, is not linear (you always need at least one range scan).

However, the filtering condition in method `2` is selective enough for the `RANGE SCAN` with a subsequent sort to be more efficient than a `FULL SCAN` for the whole table.

This means that there is a tipping point: for this condition: `ROWNUM <= X` there exists a value of `X` so that method `2` becomes more efficient when this value is exceeded.

**Update:**

If you are always searching on at least `3` first symbols, you can create an index like this:

```
SUBSTRING(UPPER(customerpostcode), 1, 3), proposalnumber
```

and use it in this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    cr_proposalsearch ps
        WHERE   SUBSTRING(UPPER(customerpostcode, 1, 3)) = SUBSTRING(UPPER(:searchquery), 1, 3)
                AND UPPER(ps.customerpostcode) LIKE UPPER(:searchquery) || '%'
        ORDER BY
                proposalNumber DESC
        )
WHERE   rownum <= 200
```

This way, the number order will be preserved separately for each set of codes sharing first `3` letters which will give you a more dense index scan.